# Data fetching issues from table which is using jinja2 (django)

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have a table which contains some list of student from my database, I want to fetch data from that html table which contains data from database but I want to add if the student is present or not.

I have a code which works perfectly but there is an issue that my functions only takes last row data and skips all other rows.

**HTML** code

```
<div class="container">
  <form method="POST" action="takeattendance">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4 style="color:white;"> Select Subject For Attendance</h4>
      <select class="btn btn-success" name="subject">
          <option selected disabled="true">Subject</option>
          {% for sub in subjects%}
          <option value="{{ sub.id }}">{{sub.subject_name}}</option>
          {%endfor%}
      </select>
  </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Email</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Roll No.</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>First Name</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Last Name</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Year</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Division</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Batch</b></th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:white;"><b>Attendance</b></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for student in students %}
            {% if user.staff.class_coordinator_of  == student.division and user.staff.teacher_of_year == student.year %}
          <tr>
            <td style="color:white;"><input type="hidden" name="student_name" value="{{student.id}}" >{{student.user}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.roll_no}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.user.first_name}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.user.last_name}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.year}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.division}}</td>
            <td style="color:white;">{{student.batch}}</td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="btn btn-success" name="status" id="status">
                    <option selected value="Present">Present</option>
                    <option value="Absent">Absent</option>
                </select>
                </div>                 
            </td>
          </tr>
          {%  endif %}          
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody> 
      </table>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg ">Add</button>
    </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

**views.py**

```
def takeattendance(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        subject = Subject.objects.get(id=request.POST['subject'])
        student = Student.objects.get(id=request.POST['student_name'])
        status = request.POST['status']
        print(subject)
        print(student)
        print(status)
        attendance = Attendance(subject=subject, student=student, status=status)
        attendance.save()

        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 2:
            return render(request,'ms/hod/Attendance.html')

        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 3:
           return render(request,'ms/staff/Attendance.html')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Failed")

    else:    
        return HttpResponse("Failed")
```

The above code works perfectly but only gets the last row data, whereas I want all the rows and the attendance of every student of every row

Comment: So you want to add all the rows of students in one request ?

Comment: yes i want to do that with there attendance whether they are present or absent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`.getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)** if you want to get multiple data from a single key

**Example 1**

```
def takeattendance(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        subject = Subject.objects.get(id=request.POST['subject'])
        student_ids = request.POST.getlist('student_name')
        status = request.POST['status']

        for sid in student_ids:
            Attendance.objects.create(
                subject=subject,
                student=Student.objects.get(id=sid),
                status=status
            )

        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 2:
            return render(request,'ms/hod/Attendance.html')

        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 3:
           return render(request,'ms/staff/Attendance.html')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Failed")

    else:    
        return HttpResponse("Failed")
```

above code will work fine but it will hit database on each iteration to solve that you can use **[`.bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)**

**Example 2**

```
def takeattendance(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        subject = Subject.objects.get(id=request.POST['subject'])
        student_ids = request.POST.getlist('student_name')
        status = request.POST['status']

        attendance_objs = []
        for sid in student_ids:
            attendance_objs.append(
                Attendance(
                  subject=subject,
                  student=Student.objects.get(id=sid),
                  status=status
                )
            )
        
        Attendance.objects.bulk_create(
                attendance_objs
        )

        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 2:
            return render(request,'ms/hod/Attendance.html')

        if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type == 3:
           return render(request,'ms/staff/Attendance.html')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Failed")

    else:    
        return HttpResponse("Failed")
```

> **Note**
>
> Before using ***`bulk_create()`*** I will suggest you to read some
> caveats of
> **[`.bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)**

Comment: I used 2nd Example but the problem is the attendance is not stored properly if I change the attendance of 1 student it keeps the same for all other students. please help me with it

Comment: So you wanted to add attandance for indivisual student from table of students ?

Comment: I want by default every thing should be present only the student I make absent should be made absent and should save the data of all at one click after selecting there attendance that is in the bulk same as above

Comment: *by default every thing should be present only the student I make absent should be made absent* -  are you selecting students (eg. `checkbox`) to make them absent ?

Comment: No I am using a dropdown toggle which has Present and a Absent option

Comment: Yes, I got that but by default all studets are in your table so if you select absent it will set absent for all students in table if you want to absent specific students then you've to select indivisual student

Comment: So if you want to select indivisual students then you've to write javascript for that and have to make a ajax call

Comment: Then What method can I use for this to fix may I know please may I get any reference for ajax and javascript please

Comment: As I said above you've to write javascript which will collect id's of all selected students & after that you've to make ajax request so that it will send specific id's to server

Comment: Can I get that javascript + ajax code please I don't know how to create that

Comment: Yes, sure I'll provide that but not in this question becouse it's contain too much code in my answer it will be greate if you ask new question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247651/discussion-between-ajay-and-ankit-tiwari).